# How can i get the input of a user and display the answer into a label for example in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-label

I'm trying to create a basic calculator with Tkinter.

Basically the user types in the radius of a circle and then it should print out the diameter, circumference and the area of the circle.

I've been experimenting with `Entry()` and `.get()` but yeah i haven't found out anything yet about my problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
radius = tk.DoubleVar()
radius_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=radius)
radius_entry.pack()
```

Then if you run `radius.get()` you get the current entry.

You can also track when the input changes with trace: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/

I recommend taking a look at an online tutorial for learning tkinter to get more information. This tutorial helped me a lot when I started tkinter: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/